# How to Checked checkboxes on top MVC Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using mvc telerik grid on my project and i have checbox inside this grid

I just want to put my checked checkbox on top

Is it possible?

Is there any experience for this situation to help me?

```
         @( Html.Telerik().Grid<Orpac.Models.Time>()
               .Name("timecmb")
               .NoRecordsTemplate("No users to display")
               .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.Ident))
               .DataBinding(d => d.Ajax().Select("GridTimeBinding", "Rule"))
               .Columns(c =>{c.Bound(e => e.Ident).Width(90).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='123' value='<#= Code #>'   <#=bit? checked='checked' : '' #> />").Title((string)ViewData["Select"]);c.Bound(e=>e.Code).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["TimeCode"]);c.Bound(e=>e.Desc).Width(300).Title((string)ViewData["Description"]); })         
               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onrowDataBoundtimepopup").OnDataBound("onDataBoundTimeRule"))
              .Selectable()
              .Footer(true)
              .Sortable()
              .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled((bool)ViewData["filtering"]))
              .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(190))
              .Pageable(p=>p.PageSize(10))
              )
```

This is example of my grid

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so you say:

```
.HeaderTemplate(
                    @<text>
                        <input type="checkbox" title="check all records" id="checkAllRecords" />
                    </text>
                )
```

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/headerfootertemplates

Comment: No. I just want to do this when the grid open checked values must be on up of the list unchecked checkboxes must be down like this

Comment: I did not can make a jsfiddler?

Comment: Actually i dont know too and i dont have any js for this . Think it i checked 3 checkbox and save grid when i open the grid again i just want to see that selected checkbox on top or list of top is it about ordering?